# Using MassTransit with StructureMap Registry classes

Tags: structuremap, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit (5.5.5) with StructureMap (4.7) in a large code base, using Registry classes to keep my dependencies organized, following what's outlined [here](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/structuremap.html):

```
class BusRegistry : Registry
{
    public BusRegistry()
    {
        For<IBusControl>(new SingletonLifecycle())
            .Use(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(x =>
            {
                x.ReceiveEndpoint("customer_update_queue", e => e.LoadFrom(context));
            }));
        Forward<IBusControl, IBus>();
    }
}

// Snip...

public void CreateContainer()
{
    _container = new Container(x => {
        x.AddRegistry(new BusRegistry());
    });
}
```

However, the LoadFrom extension method used in the call to ReceiveEndpoint is deprecated.  So how is one supposed to use MassTransit with StructureMap Registry classes currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably isn't going to be a good answer, since StructureMap is on its way out.  I ended up not using StructureMap for consumer configuration:

```
class BusRegistry : Registry
{
    public BusRegistry()
    {
        For<IBusControl>(new SingletonLifecycle())
            .Use(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(x =>
            {
                x.ReceiveEndpoint("customer_update_queue", endpointCfg => {
                    endpointCfg.Consumer<FirstSubscriber>(
                        GetFirstSubscriberFactoryMethod()
                    );
                    endpointCfg.Consumer<SecondSubscriber>(
                        GetSecondSubscriberFactoryMethod()
                    );
                    // etc...
                });
            }));
        Forward<IBusControl, IBus>();
    }
}
```

...though I am using StructureMap to inject dependencies into the consumers.